# gstreamer httplive streaming by soup plugin

Tags: streaming, http, gstreamer

I want to stream video from webcam by http live. I found that `souphttpclientsink` plugin can do this.

But when I run this command:
`gst-launch-1.0  videotestsrc ! avenc_mpeg4 ! mpegtsmux ! souphttpclientsink location=http://127.0.0.1:8080`

I got this error:
`GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHttpClientSink:souphttpclientsink0: Could not write to HTTP URI`
and
`gstsouphttpclientsink.c(728): gst_soup_http_client_sink_render (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstSoupHttpClientSink:souphttpclientsink0:

error: 4 Cannot connect to destination (127.0.0.1)`

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you solved this ? You need an HTTP streaming server running at the location. I'm trying to do the same, but I did not yet find a working solution.

Comment: I use nginx-rtmp, but since gstreamer 1.2 it include hlssink element, try to use it.